# Array Definitions for Java

Tags: java, arrays, definition

I keep trying to read through the book and re-evaluate, but I just am not getting arrays. They are not making any sense to me whatsoever. I just recently took a quiz and I missed one of these questions, but can't figure it out! It is really bugging me because I need to know the answer for the test in the future. If there is any tutorial on arrays and how they work please let me know about it because I am lost. Here is the few definitions that were on the quiz and I'm not sure which one is incorrect. The answers that are bolded are my answers.

Question 1:
Which of the following initializer lists correctly initializes the indexed variables of an array named myDoubles?

double myDoubles[double] = {0.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5};

double myDoubles[5] = new double(0.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5);

**double[] myDoubles = {0.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5};**

array myDoubles[double] = {0.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5};

Question 2:
When calling a method, the correct syntax for passing an array as an argument in a method is:

method(a[]);

method(a());

**method(a);**

method(int a[]);

Question 3:
An array is a collection of variables all of the same type.
    **True**
    False

Question 4:
An arrays length instance variables value can be changed by a program.
    True
    **False**

Question 5:
An array of chars is the same as a String in Java.
    True
    **False**

Question 6:
An array name references a memory address.
    **True**
    False

Question 7:
Arrays are objects that are created with new just like class objects.
    True
    **False**

Comment: try yourself, you will get all answers

Comment: I googled for "java arrays" and in the first link found [The Official Oracle Arrays Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 7 is answered incorrectly. Arrays *are* objects.

[Java Language Specification, section 4.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1):

> An object is a class instance or an array.